# VS code python interactive terminal doesn't find changes in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have a module that contains a class and a couple of functions that I will call package.
The directory of that package is added to PYTHONPATH in the .bashrc (I'm on linux) and and in the interactive jupyter window I navigated to the directory of the package via os.chdir(). VS code is using my global python installation.

I have a script script.py that imports the module and calls the function f1().
Something like

```
import package

example = package.class1()
example.f1()
```

I can run the function and it produces output in the interactive python window. However, if I do changes in the script, let's say I change a variable or add a print('something') function somewhere, nothing changes. If I run the code in the terminal (not the interactive python thing), the output is produced correctly. Why doesn't the interactive python window see these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described: When the content of this document is changed, "`Interactive`" will be changed accordingly;
When the content of the called file is changed, "`Interactive`" will not automatically update the data.

We need to click the `refresh button` above "`Interactive`" to update the cache content and the data will be updated accordingly. (Or reopen an "Interactive".) Obviously, using the previous cache when calling will shorten the running time and improve efficiency.

Thank you for posting this problem here, we have submitted it, and let us look forward to a better solution.

Github link: [When the content of the called file is changed, "Interactive" does not update the data accordingly](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15056).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. That's, however, super disappointing. My workflow consists usually in changing something in a package that I'm writing, and then run a test script and play around with the variables in the interactive window. This is honestly even a reason to switch back to something like spyder. 
How do other people do it? Only use the terminal?